# Changing a Vanilla Item in Minecraft Forge 1.18.2

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So, I'm new to modding Minecraft, and I want to change the Grass Block. All the tutorials I have found so far, however, are for older versions, and what they suggest simply doesn't seem to work anymore. Right now I am trying to register a new Block like this:

```
public static final RegistryObject<Block> GRASS_BLOCK = registerBlock("minecraft:grass_block", () -> new SiltBlock(BlockBehaviour.Properties.copy(Blocks.DIRT)), CreativeModeTab.TAB_BUILDING_BLOCKS);

private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> registerBlock(String name, Supplier<T> block, CreativeModeTab tab) {
    RegistryObject<T> toReturn = BLOCKS.register(name, block);
    return toReturn;
}
```

Interestingly, while my normal registrations work this way, this one doesn't just not work, it actually causes an error when loading the Mod. It seems like I'm on the right track, apparently already accessing the Vanilla Block, but I do not know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i found out recently that it's very simple.
Simply create another `DeferredRegister` and replace your mod id with "minecraft". So the code should be like:

```
public static final DeferredRegister<Block> VANILLA_BLOCKS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS, "minecraft");

public static final RegistryObject<Block> GRASS_BLOCK = registerBlock("grass_block", () -> new SiltBlock(BlockBehaviour.Properties.copy(Blocks.DIRT)), CreativeModeTab.TAB_BUILDING_BLOCKS);
    
private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> registerBlock(String name, Supplier<T> block, CreativeModeTab tab) {
        RegistryObject<T> toReturn = VANILLA_BLOCKS.register(name, block);
        return toReturn;
    }
```

And don't forget to registry the deferred register in the main file:

```
VANILLA_BLOCKS.register(eventBus);
```

Comment: This makes the original item disappear from the creative menu. So don't forget to override the block item too.